# Is there a way to disable access to the Sharing preference pane?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

We do not use Open Directory at my company but I deploy OSX images using DeployStudio. We use an inventory system that automatically updates, but users keep on changing their computer's name in the Sharing preference pane, causing our naming convention to get messed up.

Is there a way to either disable the Sharing preference pane or at least only allow some users to access it, even if others are admins?

Comment: As just a side note: There is no 100% way to prevent this, even if the user is an admin. I would agree that @slhck's method is the best, but it's still reversible to admins on the local Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're up for it, you can remove the *Sharing* preference pane by simply renaming it.

```
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/SharingPref.prefPane
```

For example, rename it to `SharingPref` without an extension. You need admin privileges for that, and of course it's reversible if the user knows where to look, but if you have to fight against users who just "want to change their computer name", I guess that'll do?

Before and after:

[image: Before]
[image: After]